# Can't get form's select element value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to get input element's value using 
`var flt=$("#flt"+rowID).val();`

but cannot get `select elements value`

here is my php code

```
<?php
    $AC= & getAC();
    while ($rowAC=mysql_fetch_array($AC)){
        $i++;
        if ($rowAC['acode']==$row['TPE']){
            echo "<option value='{$rowAC['acode']}' selected='selected'>{$rowAC['name_ru']}</option>";  
        }else{
            echo "<option value='{$rowAC['acode']}'>{$rowAC['name_ru']}</option>";                  
        }

    }
?>
```

I am generating list using this php code but

cannot even getting it's text value coding in such a way

```
var tpe=$("#tpe option[value='2']").text();
window.alert(tpe);
```

I am concerned only to get it's option value!!!
How to get it???

Comment: Can you post the actual html that gets rendered by the php?

Comment: It's all the same when I change to !!!

Comment: here is the html code `<select name="tpe" id="tpe1" >
            <option value='14'>А319</option><option value='15'>А320</option><option value='12'>АН24</option><option value='13'>АН26</option><option value='8'>Б732</option><option value='4'>Б733</option><option value='5' selected='selected'>Б734</option><option value='1'>Б735</option><option value='6'>Б737</option><option value='3'>Б738</option><option value='2'>Б752</option><option value='7'>Б757</option><option value='9'>ТУ134</option><option value='11'>ТУ154</option><option value='10'>ЯК40</option>    
            </select>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some quick testing, it appears that `value()` only works on the `select` element itself. To get the value of the different `option` elements, you can use `attr('value')` on the option elements themselves.

Very quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/y9Dqg/2/

Comment: @SuhrobSamiev: You can get the selected `option` element only with `$('#tpe option[selected]')`, I think

Comment: I am using `$('#tpe'+id+' option:selected').val();` and it's working! Everything is fine with your help! Thank you @Flambino, for the answer!!!